# microsoft sql create date for every line in a join

Tags: sql, date, join

I need to query trends for every client. Since not all the clients bought something each month, there will be month where I get no data for that client, but I still need to see the month in zero.

I created a table with every month for the period I want to see:

```
select DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(loaddate)-1),loaddate),126) AS meses
into dbo.gp_MESES
FROM CustomerDebits AS D WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE LOADDATE>='20130101' AND LOADDATE<=GETDATE() 
ORDER BY 1;
```

and lef joned with the purchases of each client in each month.

```
SELECT CODEMP, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(loaddate)-1),loaddate),126) AS FECHA_MES, 
COUNT(*) AS Q_CLIENTES
INTO DBO.GP_TEND_0
FROM  CustomerDebits AS D WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE LOADDATE<=GETDATE() AND LOADDATE>='20130101'
GROUP BY CODEMP, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(loaddate)-1),loaddate),126);
```

The problem is that when the customer didn't bough anything I still don't see the line in 0. I was thinking of creating a table with every combination of clients-months and after that do the left join, but it's not efficient.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your db schema?  Looks to me you're querying the `CustomerDebits` table which will only have debits--not actual customers.  For the full list of customers you'll probably need to `JOIN` on the `customers` table.

Comment: I don't care about having all customers. I only want that if I have a customer once, to have all the month after they started, even if they are in zero.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean by this or what 'in zero' means.

Comment: if you have a client that bought in jan by didn't bought in february, you will have no line for february for that client, and stil I need to have february in 0 for that client. With month left join purchases by client I don't get the line in 0 (I just don't get the line at all for that client).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to full outer join dbo.gp_MESES table to DBO.GP_TEND_0 on meses = FECHA_MES and exploit the NULLs to get the zero value that you're looking for.

I envision something like this:

```
    SELECT COALESCE(T2.FECHA_MES, T1.MESES) AS MONTH --THIS WILL PULL MESES WHERE FECHA_MES IS NULL
    ,T2.CODEMP
    ,ISNULL(T2.Q_CLIENTES, 0) AS PURCHASES --THIS WILL GIVE YOU 0 WHERE Q_CLIENTES IS NULL
   FROM dbo.gp_MESES T1
   FULL OUTER JOIN DBO.GP_TEND_0 T2 
   ON T1.MESES = T2.FECHA_MES
```

Comment: It doesn't do that. I still get the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't get the same result, but I see now that you'll get a NULL CODEMP where the purchases are 0. I think that you'll need to bump up your list of months against your distinct list of customers, and then full outer join THAT to DBO.GP_TEND_0, using the ISNULL(T2.Q_CLIENTES, 0) AS PURCHASES solution above. If you're concerned about efficiency, there's probably a better way to populate your gp_MESES table if CustomerDebits is a large table. I bet doing a loop that inserts one month while startdate <= enddate and the startdate = 12/1/2013 and enddate = getdate() would help a lot.